# Why make virtual destructors sense?

Tags: virtual, virtual-destructor

I know they're used to get the destructor of any sub classes called (when deleting a pointer).
But what happens in the background?

I mean a sub class inherits this virtual destructor of its base class. Inherit something means for me to get something as it is. But in this case the sub class doesn't get the same destructor that the base class has. (Maybe it gets the same especially if it has no body).
The point is, it does other things even if the sub class does not redefine it. So how does this works?

Let's say we have (C++):

```
class BaseClass{
  int i;
  public:
  virtual ~BaseClass(){}
};

class SubClass: public BaseClass{
  int j;
};

BaseClass* bptr = new SubClass;
delete bprt;
```

In this case we want the program to deallocate the memory a object of type SubClass needs. That is, the inherited int i and the own int j.
If we had no virtual destructor in BaseClass then a default-generated destructor in BaseClass would be used (it has an empty body and after this, all members of BaseClass would be deleted and the memory deallocated).

The big question is: The virtual destructor in BaseClass will be inherited by SubClass but SubClass does not redefine it. Why does the inherited destructor more than it does in the class that it is inherited from? (it deletes both integers i and j when executed on a SubClass object)

Comment: Is this C++? And yet the classes don't have semicolons on the end, but it can't be C#, .... oh for a language tag

Comment: Now they have semicolons;) Yes it is C++

Comment: I'm not clear what " Why does the inherited destructor more than it does in the class that it is inherited from?" means

Comment: I mean: In the derived class we inherit the destructor from base class. That destructor has to do more actions than it had to do in base class because in the sub class we have one more integer to delete.      You said I will get a default-destructor generated by the compiler because I don't define one by myself. But what's with the inherited one?

Answer (score 0):

First, just as `new` both allocates memory and then runs a constructor, `delete` will run destructors and then free up memory.

When you make a new `SubClass` it first creates the `BaseClass` and runs its constructor then makes the `SubClass` and runs its constructor.

When we call delete, the deconstruction happens in the opposite order. First, the `Subclass` is destructed, then the `BaseClass`.

Notice, first this differs from other virtual functions - just one instance of an overridden function would be called. Destructors are special.

If the `BaseClass` is not virtual, they when you call `delete bprt;` just the `BaseClass` destructor gets called. This is bad.

In your case you have a virtual base destructor and haven't explicitly written your own (and you haven't made it impossible for the compiler to generated one for you) so the compiler generates one for you. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

Why did it bother? Because the destructor will get called when you `delete` a `new`ed object or it goes out of scope. Does it "do more" - well no, not in this case.

Comment: The "more" I mean is deallocation of memory. SubClass has one more integer to deallocate. And it's deallocation works although the inherited base class destructor is used which can't know about this additional integer. But you said the compiler will create a new destructor for `SubClass` so I guess that one will be used.

Comment: Both destructors get called, in reverse order of the constructors

Comment: Ok, guess I got it now;) Thx